# Make Compile Fail on Non-Exhaustive Match in SBT

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, sbt

Let's say that I have a trait, Parent, with one child, Child.

```
scala> sealed trait Parent
defined trait Parent

scala> case object Boy extends Parent
defined module Boy
```

I write a function that pattern matches on the sealed trait. My `f` function is **total** since there's only a single `Parent` instance.

```
scala> def f(p: Parent): Boolean = p match { 
     |   case Boy => true
     | }
f: (p: Parent)Boolean
```

Then, 2 months later, I decide to add a `Girl` child of `Parent`.

```
scala> case object Girl extends Parent
defined module Girl
```

And then re-write the `f` method since we're using REPL.

```
scala> def f(p: Parent): Boolean = p match { 
     |   case Boy => true
     | }
<console>:10: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Girl
       def f(p: Parent): Boolean = p match { 
                                   ^
f: (p: Parent)Boolean
```

If I were to encounter a non-exhaustive match, then I'd get a compile-time warning (as we see here).

However, how can I make the compilation **fail** on a non-exhaustive match?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add `-Xfatal-warnings` to Scalac's options. That way any warning will be treated as an error.

In sbt, you can achieve that with:

```
scalacOptions += "-Xfatal-warnings"
```

Comment: This technically answers the question, but it's often not a viable solution. I'd personally be interested in seeing answers that don't require failing on all warnings, even if they're messier.

Comment: @TravisBrown: Short of writing your own compiler plugin or SBT plugin, this is the only solution available.

Comment: @TravisBrown, why is it often not a "viable" solution?

Comment: @KevinMeredith When you're working on a project that has lots of warnings that you don't care about.

Comment: @Kim Stebel : old school but works: redirect the output to a file and look for the warning. In Jenkins you can make the build fail when it finds certain patterns in the log file.

Answer (score 9):

Since scalac 2.13.2 there's a fairly granular control of warnings. To get what OP asks:

> ```
> scalacOptions += "-Wconf:cat=other-match-analysis:error"
> ```

[Detailed howto by Lukas Rytz.](https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/01/12/configuring-and-suppressing-warnings.html)

Comment: Also the scala compiler option -Ypatmat-exhaust-depth can be useful, more info at https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html

Comment: Note: This was also backported to Scala 2.12.13+

Answer (score 0):

A compiler flag for Sbt and Scala **3** :

`scalacOptions += "-Ycheck-all-patmat"`

Many flags for Scala 2 do not work with Scala 3.

[migration notes Scala 2 -> 3](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/options-intro.html)

[more on Scala 3 compiler flags](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/options-new.html)

Answer (score -7):

Perhaps you could put in a default case to catch post-defined elements and bind it to a partial function which you can manage separately. Then the partial will act as a "default handler".

```
  sealed trait Animal
  case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal
  case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal

  val t: Animal = Dog("fido")

  // updates when the trait updates
  val partial = PartialFunction[Animal, Unit] {
    case Dog(_) => println("default dog")
    case Cat(_) => println("default cat")
    case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Broken")
  }

  // matches that may be out of date refer to it
  t match {
    case Dog(_) => println("specific dog")
    case t => partial(t)
  }
```

Or perhaps you can just use PartialFunctions all the way through and chain them together.

Comment: This solution brings a lot for boilerplate into codebase. Moreover, OP asks about SBT options to achieve this.

Comment: Strange to comment so long after the question, but with 3 years of hindsight -- his problem is that he chose pattern matching in the first place.  If he used something like a type class he could get the compiler failure he wants, and probably with less code.

Comment: Sorry to comment again after such a long time. Could you extrapolate on the type class approach? I'm having a similar issue here.